# SQL Plus Nested Select Statements

Tags: inner-join, sqlplus

I am trying to get the vehicle_Code from the Vehicles table which is a sequential number for a distinct make and model combination. The description of the Vehicles table is the make and model concatenation. The VIN in the Sales table aligns with the make and model of the OTLP_Vehicles table. I am unsure how to modify my JOIN and possibly add a WHERE clause to get the vehicle_Code.

Here is my current script:

```
SELECT sale_date,vehicle_Code,sf.plan_ID,dealer_ID,
    COUNT (*) AS vehicles_sold,
    SUM (s.gross_sale_price) AS gross_sales_amt
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Sales_Financings sf 
 on sf.sale_ID = s.sale_ID 
GROUP BY sale_date, vehicle_Code, sf.plan_ID, dealer_ID;
```

Describes of the tables I need to use for the vehicle_Code:

```
SQL> desc Sales
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
SALE_ID                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
SALESPERSON_ID                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
CUST_ID                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
SALE_DATE                                          DATE
VIN                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
MILEAGE                                            NUMBER(38)
VEHICLE_STATUS                                     VARCHAR2(15)
GROSS_SALE_PRICE                          NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
DEALER_ID                                          VARCHAR2(5)
VEHICLE_CODE                                       VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc Vehicles
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
VEHICLE_CODE                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> desc OLTP_Vehicles
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
VIN                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
TRADE_ID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
TYPE                                               VARCHAR2(10)
MAKE                                               VARCHAR2(15)
MODEL                                              VARCHAR2(15)
WHERE_FROM                                         VARCHAR2(30)
WHOLESALE_COST                            NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
```

Here is a subset of the data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM Vehicles;

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
1               Ford, Fiesta
2               Chevrolet, Tahoe
3               Chevrolet, Colorado
4               Ford, Taurus
5               Ford, F-150
6               Chevrolet, Silverado
7               Ford, Focus
8               Dodge, Charger
9               Dodge, Challenger
10              Chevrolet, Suburban
11              Ford, Expedition

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
12              Ford, F-350
13              Dodge, Dakota
14              Ford, Edge
15              Dodge, Durango
16              Ford, F-250
17              Chevrolet, Corvette
18              Ford, Fusion
19              Dodge, Ram
20              Chevrolet, Impala
21              Chevrolet, Malibu
22              Chevrolet, Camaro

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
23              Chevrolet, Camaro

23 rows selected.

SQL> Select * From OLTP_Vehicles;
VIN                  TRADE_ID   TYPE       MAKE            MODEL           WHERE_FROM            WHOLESALE_COST
-------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- -------------------- ---------------
98765432FV87654321V0 9009009000 Truck      Chevrolet       Silverado       Washington, DC            $45,000.00
25667894FC36948523V8 9009009001 Car        Ford            Fusion          Virginia                  $14,000.00
95786985HC58635889C2 9009009002 Car        Chevrolet       Camaro          Maryland                  $35,000.00
95678234FV53375329V5 9009009003 Truck      Dodge           Ram             Maryland                  $35,000.00
93678247HC45852485F5 9009009004 Truck      Dodge           Dakota          Washington, DC            $25,000.00
25786785HV45785547T4 9009009005 Car        Ford            Focus           Washington, DC            $15,000.00
27894578FC56778852C5 9009009006 Truck      Chevrolet       Silverado       Virginia                   $9,000.00
93678574HV45886348V5 9009009007 Car        Ford            Fiesta          Maryland                  $13,000.00
68975324HF45885337C6 9009009008 Car        Dodge           Charger         Washington, DC            $35,000.00
98768859HC58785672H2 9009009009 Truck      Chevrolet       Colorado        Washington, DC            $20,000.00
96587453GH45772535C1 9009009010 Truck      Chevrolet       Silverado       Virginia                  $40,000.00

SQL> Select * From Sales;

SALE_ID    SALESPERSO CUST_ID    SALE_DATE VIN                     MILEAGE VEHICLE_STATUS  GROSS_SALE_PRICE DEALE VEHICLE_CODE
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- -------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------------- ----- ---------------
3000001000 6000000600 1000100000 17-FEB-28 98765432FV87654321V0          0 New                   $55,000.00 D0001
3000001001 6000000601 1000100100 17-MAR-13 25667894FC36948523V8      25000 Used                  $24,000.00 D0002
3000001002 6000000602 1000100200 17-MAY-02 95786985HC58635889C2          4 New                   $45,000.00 D0003
3000001003 6000000603 1000100300 17-JUN-10 95678234FV53375329V5          3 New                   $45,000.00 D0001
3000001004 6000000604 1000100400 17-JAN-09 93678247HC45852485F5      45666 Used                  $35,000.00 D0002
3000001005 6000000605 1000100500 17-DEC-12 25786785HV45785547T4          0 New                   $25,000.00 D0003
3000001006 6000000606 1000100600 17-NOV-31 27894578FC56778852C5     174000 Used                  $19,000.00 D0001
3000001007 6000000607 1000100700 17-OCT-25 93678574HV45886348V5          1 New                   $23,000.00 D0002
3000001008 6000000608 1000100800 17-AUG-22 68975324HF45885337C6         15 New                   $45,000.00 D0003
3000001009 6000000609 1000100900 17-JUL-01 98768859HC58785672H2      35000 Used                  $30,000.00 D0001
3000001010 6000000600 1000100000 17-JUL-01 96587453GH45772535C1          3 New                   $50,000.00 D0002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically this can be done using concatenation.

```js
SELECT 
 * --INSERT YOUR COLUMNS
FROM
 Sales s
INNER JOIN
 OLTP_Vehicles OV ON OV.VIN = s.VIN
INNER JOIN
 Vehicles V ON CONCAT(OV.MAKE, ', ',OV.MODEL) = V.DESCRIPTION
```

Please do let me know if this works.

Here is a DB fiddle of the same using PostGreSQL

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8UQauTHpv9GhGYXoNK2TYW/0

Comment: I ran this:SELECT sale_date,v.vehicle_Code,sf.plan_ID,dealer_ID,
  COUNT (*) AS vehicles_sold,
  SUM (s.gross_sale_price) AS gross_sales_amt
 FROM Sales s
 INNER JOIN Sales_Financings sf 
  on sf.sale_ID = s.sale_ID 
 INNER JOIN OLTP_Vehicles ov
  on ov.VIN = s.VIN
 INNER JOIN Vehicles v
  on ov.make + ', ' + ov.model = v.description
 GROUP BY sale_date, v.vehicle_Code, sf.plan_ID, dealer_ID; and I got a ORA-01722: invalid number for on ov.make + ', ' + ov.model = v.description. This looks like it returns the description and not the vehicle_Code in the Vehicles table?

Comment: That is strange. Let me recreate the schema and data at my end. Please give me some time.

Comment: Here is a DB fiddle, with the same concept using PostGreSQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8UQauTHpv9GhGYXoNK2TYW/0